# Class function correct output but wrong method

Tags: python, python-3.x

My homework question asks me to write the following functions using a predetermined class 'Person', it runs 5 tests, one code analyser that ensures it was done the way they want and 4 practical examples, my code passes the practical examples but the analyser fails me.

This is the question:

Using the Person class, write a function print_friend_info(person) which accepts a single argument, of type Person, and:

prints out their name

prints out their age

if the person has any friends, prints 'Friends with {name}'

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age, gender):
        self._name = name
        self._age = age
        self._gender = gender
        self._friend = None

    def __eq__(self, person):
        return str(self) == str(person)

    def __str__(self):
        if self._gender == 'M':
            title = 'Mr'
        elif self._gender == 'F':
            title = 'Miss'
        else:
            title = 'Ms'

        return title + ' ' + self._name + ' ' + str(self._age)

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Person: ' + str(self)

    def get_name(self):
        """
        (str) Return the name

        """
        return self._name

    def get_age(self):
        """
        (int) Return the age

        """
        return self._age

    def get_gender(self):
        """
        (str) Return the gender

        """
        return self._gender

    def set_friend(self, friend):
        self._friend = friend

    def get_friend(self):
        """
        (Person) Return the friend

        """
        return self._friend

def print_friend_info(person):
    print(person._name)
    print(person._age)
    if person.get_friend() != None:
        print("Friends with {}".format(person._friend._name))
```

All tests pass, including the `print_friend_info` tests, except for this test that outputs the following error:

> **----- Analysis Errors -----**
>
> You need to print the person's name in print_friend_info
>
> You need to print the person's age in print_friend_info
>
> You need to print the name of the person's friend in print_friend_info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried your code and it works for me with Python3.6.6. I have some suggestions which could be problem. First of all your shouldn't use the protected attributes of your class (underscored variables). You have getter methods to get the data of object so use them. It seems to me that the output can fulfill the test what you mentioned in your question.

**Changed part of code:**

```
def print_friend_info(person):
    print("Name: {}".format(person.get_name()))
    print("Age: {}".format(person.get_age()))
    if person.get_friend():  # You don't need to use "!= None". A simple if is enough.
        print("Friends with {}".format(person.get_friend().get_name())
    print("\n")


joe = Person("Joe", 42, "Male")
print_friend_info(joe)
mary = Person("Mary", 55, "Female")
print_friend_info(mary)
joe.set_friend(mary)
print_friend_info(joe)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
Name: Joe
Age: 42


Name: Mary
Age: 55


Name: Joe
Age: 42
Friends with Mary
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced every instance of x._name with x.get_name() and it worked. Could you explain why this makes any difference given that the get_name(self) function simply outputs self._name?

Comment: You can get the same value with the getter method and with the protected attribute but the variable is protected so you should not use it outside of object. Python allow to use it bat the Pylint says you shouldn't do it. Usage of protected attributes could be safety question. You can read more details about Python protected/private members: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/private-and-protected-access-modifiers-in-python